# VB.NET Retrieve File path of File in Parent directory without parent Directory path included

Tags: vb.net

So I have a directory where i want to get for all files in all including subdirs, the path of them relative to the parent directory.
Example:

```
Parent directory: "C:\test"
File1 located in: "C:\test\foo\bar.txt"
```

what i want to retrieve is:

```
"foo\bar.txt"
```

I know how to do it with

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(Path)
```

but that will return the full Path to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have:

```
    Dim root = "c:\temp\"
    Dim files = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(root, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)
```

Now just take the substring starting at the length of the root directory.

```
    Dim filesWithoutRoot = files.Select(Function(f) f.Substring(root.Length)).ToList
```